# IIS Users not saving correctly

Tags: c#, iis, razor-pages

Here is my scenario: I have a web application developped on Razor pages and it's published on a server with IIS connected to the company's network. I use windows identification for the user to log into the application. Each time an user makes a change or uses the application I save windows user into a SQL database. The problem is that sometimes the user is not the current user using the application. It's not frequent that this happens but I'm wondering if an user leaves the app open and another user logs in then the new user is saved? I tried to replicate the error on my local machine but I can't get to the same problem. I use `User.Identity.Name`and save the value inside a static variable. Do you know what can cause this problem?

Comment: _"and save the value inside a **static** variable"_, I would focus on the **static** variable.

Comment: As a web app on IIS is by default serving multiple users, saving something in a static variable is as horrible as it can be. Talk to a more senior developer in your organization to learn more, or hire a consultant.

Comment: thanks for your help it's my first time using IIS and I'm new to web dev in general. I just used one static variable. So using User.Identity.Name isn't an error?

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` just a method you get current user name. It isn't an error.